# Grep fails to find a substring even though i know it exists

Tags: windows, grep, cygwin

grep is failing to find a pattern in files. So i must be doing something wrong or not understanding something about grep.

Example: the following command returns the following matches:

```
grep sys_krnl_mini * -Rn
j6_run_mini.cmm:22:;DATA.LOAD D:\git\g1xxx\build\arm\debug\sys_krnl_mini\sys_krnl_mini.axf
j6_run_mini.cmm:23:;DATA.LOAD D:\git\g1xxx\build\arm\debug\sys_krnl_mini\sys_krnl_mini.axf
j6_run_mini.cmm:24:DATA.LOAD D:\git2\scratch_g1x_sgx544\g1x_sgx544\build\arm\debug\sys_krnl_mini\sys_krnl_mini.axf
grep: log.cmm: Device or resource busy
```

As you can see there are 4 matches. So i tried grepping for a sub string of those matches: build\arm\debug. But i don't get any results. Which is odd because i should get at least 3 matches.

Here is the greps i tried and the results:

```
$ grep build\arm\debug * -Rn
grep: log.cmm: Device or resource busy

$ grep build\\arm\\debug * -Rn
grep: log.cmm: Device or resource busy

$ grep 'build\arm\debug' * -Rn
grep: log.cmm: Device or resource busy

$ grep "build\arm\debug" * -Rn
grep: log.cmm: Device or resource busy

$ grep "build\\arm\\debug" * -Rn
grep: log.cmm: Device or resource busy
```

What am i doing wrong or not understanding?

Comment: Normally the flags (`-Rn` in your case) come immediately after `grep` and before the pattern and filename.

Comment: build\arm\debug is a folder - you can't search a folder, you need to search the files in a folder. Try `grep -Rn sys_krnl_mini build/arm/debug/*` or `grep -Rn sys_krnl_mini build\arm\debug\*`

Comment: build\arm\debug is *not* a folder, @Mark. It's *text* that grep found in the file *j6_run_mini.cmm* on lines 22, 23, and 24. Bob is asking how to use grep to search for that same text that it's already found once before.

Comment: @RobKennedy: Apologies, you are correct. Any idea what log.cmm is and why it is being searched and why it is inaccessible?

Comment: What happens if you search piecewise for the 3 parts? If that works, you will know it is the slashes that are messing it up. 'grep build * -Rn | grep arm | grep debug'

Comment: log.cmm is a file that is locked in the searched directories. I believe grep is just warning me that it can't search the contents of that file and then moves on.

Comment: The slashes are the problem for some reason. Doing the following command returns the expected results:

`grep -Rn arm * | grep debug | grep build`

But that still doesn't solve the problem. I should be able to grep with the string `/build/arm/debug` somehow.

Comment: Found the solution. Apparently you need to (1) enclose the string in single quotes (double quotes do NOT work) and (2) use escape chars for the backslashes.

    `grep 'build\\arm\\debug' * -Rn`

Maybe this is a Cygwin thing. Don't have a Unix box to confirm on right now.

Comment: Does your grep have a '-E' option to make it treat the search pattern as a regular expression? May be worth a try with the combinations you list in your question if it does.